# logstash-forwarder start_postion => beginning

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

I am doing centralized logging using logstash. I am using logstash-forwarder on the shipper node and ELK stack on the collector node.The issue is that i want logstash to parse the file from the beginning which is present on the shipper node. The config file logstash-forwarder.conf on the shipper has following configuration :

```
       {
          "network": {
            "servers": [ "XXX.XX.XX.XXX:5000" ],
            "timeout": 15,
            "ssl ca": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
          },
          "files": [
            {   
              "paths": [
                "/apps/newlogs.txt"
               ],
              "fields": { "type": "syslog" }
            }
           ]
        }
```

And the collector configuration is :

```
input { 
  lumberjack {
    port => 5000
    type => "logs"
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
  }   
}
filter {
if [type] == "syslog" {
grok {
     match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate}\s%{LOGLEVEL:level}\s-\s%{WORD:USE_CASE}\s:\s%{WORD:STEP_DETAIL}\s:\s\[%{WORD:XXX}\]\s:\s(?<XXX>([^\s]+))\s:\s%{GREEDYDATA:MESSAGE_DETAILS}" }
     add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
     add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
     add_tag => [ "level:%{level}" ]
     add_tag => [ "USE_CASE:%{USE_CASE}" ]

   }
}
}
output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost}
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I want that the file should be parsed from the begging and not for every event generated,Which we do easily in the logstash.conf by specifying start_position => beginning but i am unable to find a straightforward way in logstash-forwarder as the file will be present on the shipper side.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, the default behaviour for logstash-forwarder is to start from the beginning of a file - so the shipper should already be reading from the start as intended.

You haven't said what you've tried doing to diagnose the problem.  If you haven't already done so, I would temporarily bypass the collector to confirm that the shipper is working as expected and rule out potential issues with the certificates.

Comment: Thanks @petevon for giving your valuable time.Actually whenever new event is generated then only it parses it properly,but does not read from the start. To diagnose this problem i put a new file with pre-contained log statements,but it didn't picked the logs from the start.I am using version logstash-forwarder-0.3.1-1. It is also mentioned that forwarder parses the file from beginning [link](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder/issues/263) here but it is not picking up messages from start.Am i missing any config property  ? .